# Share header tag between two divs

Tags: css

I have a text in the h1 tag. I want to imitate what I have on the image. How can I have letters sitting on the bottom of the div and descenders of going to a div below it?[image]

Comment: I'd say add a negative bottom margin to the h1 to make it go lower over the next div.

Comment: Just for clarity, when you say `bottom of the div` you mean the letters should be bottom aligned instead of centered? And when you say `descenders of going to a div below it` what does that mean?

Comment: @callat that's right the letters should be bottom aligned. Descenders should spill over to the next div such as lower case y. The bottom of it should go to the div below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position` like this:

```css
.top, .bottom {
  height:100px;
}
  .top {
    background:#eaf4fe;
  }
  .bottom {
    background:#f6f4f5;
    text-align:center;
  }
h1 {
  position:relative;
  top:-25px;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could accomplish the same thing with negative `margin` and `absolute` positioning as well.

Comment: this solution works well except if a user doesn't have the right font then top -25px might not sit the words on the bottom of first div

Comment: @Dmitry if you're planning on using a custom font then you will need to be sure you are including the font in your code and you will have to adjust the top position accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just playing with position and line-height values. I think it will change depending on the font-family.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
.top,
.bottom {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0.7em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
}

.top {
  background: teal;teal
}

.bottom {
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"><h1>Made Easy</h1></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
```